# How to call a method of object1 from an object2 created in object1

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a small simulation project, where I create a control object that creates several help objects and runs the simulation or "game" loop.
One of those help objects is the GUI, where I have to implement buttons that influence the game loop (pause, continue, stop or reset).
I'm not sure if and how I can call methods belonging to the control object from the help objects.

```java
public static void main(){
    first first = new first();
}
public class first(){
    public first(){
        second second = new second();
        boolean loop = true;
        while loop{
            ...
        }
    }
    public void stop(){
        this.loop = false;
    }
}
public class second(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        first.stop/ super.stop?
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide `first` as a parameter in the constructor of `second`. Btw, class names should start with an uppercase letter. Also, you're having invalid syntax. Remove the parenthesis from the class declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Second` will need a reference to an instance of `First` in order to call a method on that instance.  You can provide it one in the constructor:

```
public class Second() {
    private final First first;

    public Second(First first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.first.stop();
    }
}
```

Then just provide that reference when you create your instance:

```
Second second = new Second(this);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have thought of that myself. Guess its time for a break.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this problem from first principles.

What do you need, to be able to call a method on an object? You need a reference to the object you want to call the method on.

If you want a helper object to call a method on the control object, the helper object needs a reference to the control object.

How can you set a value (or reference) in an object? Call a setter method or pass the value in the constructor.

**TL;DR**

So, when you construct your helper objects, pass through a reference to the control object so that they can make calls back into the control object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, no idea why I didn't think of that.